# Ubuntu One file went missing

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

I have lost the file from from Ubuntu One.
I used and modified the file yesterday,  then saved it, then did some other not related work and then put my laptop on standby until the morning. When I resumed my work and went to my ubuntu One I could not find my file there anymore. Please help!
I have ubuntu on 2 laptops and Tablet.
I then went to my windows machine and opened Ubuntu One folder and found the file but 3 days old version with .conflict added to it. Tablet is up to date but no file there.
How can I get the latest version of my file that got lost from UbuntuOne folder? 
Thank you
Yuriy

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the problems. Ubuntu One should only delete files if it is told to do so through the webUI or a computer connected to your account. On Ubuntu 11.04 and higher, and on Windows, Ubuntu One moves files to the trash. So I would check the Trash on your computers first. Another option is to [contact Ubuntu One support](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) and tell them the name of the cloud folder that contained the file. They can attempt a recovery script to recover any files that may still be on the server.

If you have the time you might try and recreate the scenario with a test document. If you are able to reproduce this behavior please file a bug so the developers can look into this. You can file a bug against the ubuntuone-client package [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug). Please include your Ubuntu One logs. These logs may contain filenames. If this is an issue for you please mark the bug as private and only the Ubuntu One developers will see the bug. Here are the steps for including the logs.

1. Open your home folder
2. Click the View->Show Hidden Files menu option
3. Open the .cache/ubuntuone folder
4. Right click on the log folder and select "Compress"
5. Click OK and you should have a file named "log.tar.gz" in the .cache/ubuntuone folder, move this file to your Desktop since it's in a hidden folder which can be hard to find in the next step
6. Attach the log.tar.gz to your bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the file missing was indeed in the thrash can. I don't know why U1 deleted it. Those reliability problems are starting to piss me off...

Answer (score 2):

Try looking in the Trash first. The file I lost was in there, and no, I didn't delete it myself.

I have files synchronized between two laptops and a desktop. A very large document that I had been working on for months went missing from a folder synchronized through Ubuntu One. It wasn't found on either of the secondary systems. However, on the system that the original synchronization was set up on, I found the file in my Trash. Thankfully I hadn't emptied the trash before noticing the file was gone.

I can guarantee that I didn't delete the file myself. I also found that an older version of the file was on the two secondary systems with the '.conflict' extension. Since these were both older, they did me no good.

It seems to me that the Ubuntu One synchronization messes up every so often and deletes a file when the file is marked as a 'conflict' on another system. I'm guessing this is because the original is no longer on that system since it was renamed by Ubuntu One. This is a major flaw since it would be very easy to lose files without realizing it until it's too late.